# Transferring data from one swing form to another

Tags: java, swing, constructor

I have two swing forms. For the sake of discussion, I shall call them `Form1` and `Form2`.

In `Form1`, I have a few toggle buttons that when clicked, change its own text and text of a label. I call `Form1` from `Form2` using the following code:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1(param1,param2);
frm.setVisible(true);
frm.pack();
frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Now I have 2 constructors in `Form1`, one with no parameters and another with parameters appropriate for the data passed above. In the latter, I call a method that uses `param1` and `param2` to change the text of the toggle buttons.

```
Button1.setText(param1);
Button2.setText(param2);
changeText();
```

The changeText() method is the one responsible for changing the text of the label based on the texts of the buttons. When `Form1` is called from `Form2`, it is able to change buttons' texts according to `param1` and `param2`; but it isn't able to change the label text. The buttons also don't change texts when clicked, so neither will the label. However when `Form1` is run on its own, it successfully performs its function. Why is that?

Comment: Please post an [SSCCEE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: If you kept your GUI data in a data model, Form1 and Form2 would have a way to keep the information consistent, and put their respective information in a consistent place.